# invoke program from CMD, with path contains white space

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

```
C:\Documents and Settings\js>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11

C:\Documents and Settings\js>cd  %JAVA_HOME%\bin

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin>%JAVA_HOME%\bin java
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to solve this white space problem?

Comment: This windows command prompt is not DOS, you are not running this in a DOS environment.

Answer (score 5):

Use quotation marks:

```
cd "%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the "Java" is an application you must do this to run.

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\"Java
```

or

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\"Java.Exe
```